# CREATE FUNCTION throws SQL Error (1064) (42000)

Tags: mariadb, delimiter, stored-functions

I'm trying to create a stored function in a MariaDB database.
I copied the function I'm trying to create from the [MariaDB Docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/):

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE x TINYINT;
  SET x = 42;
  RETURN x;
END 

//

DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

What baffles me most is that the given code is supposed to resolve the very error code I'm getting according to the MariaDB docs

> The solution is to specify a distinct delimiter for the duration of the process, using the DELIMITER command

Comment: What you say you ran works for me, just checking, what version of mariaDB do you run

Comment: And how are you issuing the command, phpMyAdmin or the command line (mysql.exe)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm running version 10.3.27-MariaDB and I'm issuing the commands using Dbeaver

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your smart question about how I issue the command. I didn't even think about whether that could make a difference. However, the command works as expected in MySql Workbench. So thanks!

Comment: Yea, WorkBench probably selected the database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think it must've been a bug in DBeaver or smth because I tried adding `use db_name` there, too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, the client I used to issue the command, DBeaver, was causing the trouble.
After switching over to MySqlWorkbench everything worked as expected.

Apparently, DBeaver didn't recognise the delimiters correctly..

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgotten to select the database you want this routine to be stored into.

So try adding a `use` as the first line

```
use `test`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION FortyTwo() RETURNS TINYINT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE x TINYINT;
  SET x = 42;
  RETURN x;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```